# Why is 1:[[]] equal to (1:[]):[]?

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension

As title says, I'm not fully grasping how haskell interprets

```
1:[[]]
```

Why does it seem to do`(1:[]):[]` ?

E: I got this thought from:

```
part'::[a] -> [[a]]
part' [] = [[]]
part' (x:xs) = p ++ [x:ys | ys <- p]
    where p = part' xs
```

Specifically from `p ++ [x:ys | ys <- p]`

E.g. for `part'[1]`: is my train of thoughts correct ?:

```
part'[1] = (part'[]) ++ [1:ys | ys <- part'[]]
--> = [[]] ++ [1:[[]]]
```

Hope this makes it clear.

Comment: I'm confused: it's not.

Comment: Can you provide a self-contained example code, along with how you ran it and what output you find confusing?

Comment: What gave you the impression that it's equal to `(1:[]):[]`? It just isn't; actually this is interpreted as `1:([]:[])`, which is quite something different. (And not really well-typed.)

Comment: @gallais: It can very well be that _I_ am understanding that very wrong!

Comment: @Isaac: yes sure; I was trying to define my own list-partioning function and after several trials and errors got it working with part'::[a] -> [[a]]
part' [] = [[]]
part' (x:xs) = p ++ [x:ys | ys <- p]
    where p = part' xs


Now my confusion comes from 'p ++ [x:ys | ys <- p]', wouldn't that in the end be '[[]] ++ x:[[]]' ?

Comment: `(1:[]):[]` is `[[1]] :: Num a => [[a]]`. Instead, `1:[[]]` is `[1,[]] :: Num [a] => [[a]]` which leads to a type error unless there is some `Num` instance for lists around.

Comment: Oh and to leftaroundabout and isaac how I came to that conclusion; trying 1:[[]] or 1:([]:[]) in ghci just returns a type error

Comment: Right, `1:[[]]` is a type error, and `(1:[]):[]` is not, so they cannot be the same... Maybe I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: @Isaac I edited with a concrete example, hopefully that clears up what I'm confused about?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems like you're misunderstanding the `[... | ys <- p]` syntax. In this case, `ys` is a stand-in for *each element* of the list `p`, not for the whole list. The equational reasoning in the last part of your question should be

```
part' [1] = (part' []) ++ [1:ys | ys <- p]
-- = [[]] ++ [1:ys | ys <- [[]]]
-- = [[]] ++ [1 : []]
-- = [[], [1]]
```

Comment: Does that mean, if e.g. `p=[1,2,3]` then `[1:ys | ys <- p]` would be `1:1:2:3:[]` ? (Instead of `1:[1,2,3]`)

Comment: No. Again, `ys` would stand in for each element of p in turn, so you'd be trying to do `[1:1, 1:2, 1:3]`, which doesn't make sense. You'd get a type error.

Comment: Oh, I think I understood where my confusion came from; so basically `[1:ys | ys <- [*[]*] ]` becomes `1: *[]*` where they then form an element of the 'inner layer' list to make `[1]` because the empty item isn't shown in a non-empty list?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "the empty item is not shown;" I think you may be misunderstanding how lists work in general. When you have `1:2:3:[]`, that list does **not contain** `[]`; `[]` simply represents the empty list, into which you're inserting those other elements. You can think of the `:` operator as saying "put the element on my left inside the list on my right," and because it is right-associative you get `1:2:[] = 1:(2:([])) = 1:([2]) = [1,2]`. Does that make sense?

Comment: I'm really sorry for all that inconvenience,... 
I _thought_ I understood how lists work, but I always thought the `:[]` in the end represented an empty list, as in a list that is empty including a placeholder _empty_ element. And adding an element to an empty list would replace that _empty element_ ... I don't know if that makes sense? - But yeah your example makes total sense.

Comment: And so what I was trying to say is that since we add the '1' to the empty list, it would replace that placeholder empty element, and it doesn't show up ! (which wouldn't be the same as the empty liste we concatenate in the full example using ++)

Comment: @user452306 there is no placeholder. An empty list is a list which is empty, it has no elements. Prepending ("consing") an element like *1* to an empty list means creating new list which has *1* in it, and then all the elements of the previous list - which in this case is *no more elements*. So in all, the new list contains *1* as its only element. Or in Haskell `1 : [ ] = [ 1 ]`. This follows from the type of `(:)` operator: `(:) :: a -> [ a ] -> [ a ]`. I.e. it takes an element, and a list of similar elements, and creates a combined list of similar elements.

Answer (score 2):

The `[]` in Haskell can be quite confusing.

The empty brackets `[]` by themselves are the constructor for an empty list. Usually this is explained by this alternative (isomorphic) list definition, where `[]` is called `Nil` and `:` is called `Cons`.

```
data List a
  = Nil
  | Cons a (List a)
```

Things don't exactly get easier when you consider that any *finite list* has `Nil` in the end. It's the only possible way to end the recursion, e.g.:

```
Cons 3 (Cons 4 (Cons 5 Nil))
```

or, equivalently:

```
3 : (4 : (5 : []))
```

Some confusion comes from this handy syntax, which expresses again the same:

```
[3, 4, 5]
```

Now someone might read `[]` as simply the `empty list` without any clue about `Cons` and `Nil`.

Yet there's more: In type signatures, you encounter things like `[Int]` or `[a]` which means `List Int` or `List a`, thus the brackets - again - express an entirely different thing.

There's the risk of a false intuition regarding the meaning of the brackets in Haskell and suddenly you have to think hard about the exact meaning of things like `[1]` and `[[1]]`, or `1:[]` and `(1:[]):[]`.

Answer (score 0):

Behold, the Lists:

```
[a,b,c] ++ [d,e,f] =
[a,b] ++ [c,d,e,f] =
[a] ++ [b,c,d,e,f] =
[] ++ [a,b,c,d,e,f] =
a : [b,c,d,e,f] =
a : b : [c,d,e,f] =
a : b : c : [d,e,f] =
a : b : c : d : [e,f] =
a : b : c : d : e : [f] =
a : b : c : d : e : f : [] =
[a,b,c,d,e,f] ++ [] =
[a,b,c,d,e] ++ [f] =
[a,b,c,d] ++ [e,f] =
[a,b,c] ++ [d,e,f]
```

and list comprehensions:

```
[[a, 0] | a <- [1,2,3]] =
     [r | a <- [1,2,3], r <- [[a, 0]]] =
            concatMap (\a -> [[a, 0]]) [1,2,3] =
[[1, 0]] ++ [[2, 0]] ++ [[3, 0]] =
[[1, 0],     [2, 0],     [3, 0]]
```